# How to delete virus on a iPad air

Tags: ipad, virus

I was using Safari when I got a pop-up saying you got a virus(7) click on ok to delete this virus and I clicked on ok because I thought I really had a virus but it said type your phone number. Should I type my phone number in or not. I tried to look up how to find and delete viruses but it is mostly Android and Microsoft products.

My iPad is an iPad air. But is it possible to get a virus on a iOS device and if so how can I find it and delete it?

Answer (score 5):

The website you were visiting was serving you a pop-up to try and get you to enter your phone number. If you just leave that website by clicking cancel and navigating away or closing the whole safari app, you should be fine. While it is technically possible to get a virus on an iOS device, it is incredibly difficult, and in this instance, I think you are safe, I would just avoid going back to that website. If you continue to have issues with your phone after leaving the website, then you might want to post here again, take it to an apple store, or simply reset the phone. But again, I think that is extremely unlikely.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are, almost always, a scam, trying to get your data, such as phone numbers or email addresses. Leave those sites immediately! Don't worry, getting malware on your iPad is almost impossible with normal use, and even if you did, websites wouldn't be able to check that.